# MongoDB aggregations group by and count with a join

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have MongoDB model called `candidates`

```
 appliedJobs: [
      {
        job: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "JobPost" },
        date:Date
      },
    ],
```

candidate may have multiple records in `appliedJobs` array. There I refer to the `jobPost`.
`jobPost` has the `companyName`, property.

```
companyName: String,
```

What I want is to get the company names with send job applications counts. For an example

```
|Company|Applications|
|--------|---------------|
|Facebook|10 applications|
|Google|5 applications|
```

I created this query

```
 Candidate.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          appliedJobs: { $exists: true },
        },
      },
      { $group: { _id: '$companyName', count: { $sum: 1 } } },
    ])
```

The problem here is I can't access the `companyName` like this. Because it's on another collection. How do I solve this?

Comment: If your expected result is for all candidates together use @ray's answer. If you want a result per candidate, you can use my answer...It is not so clear what is your expected result

Answer (score 0):

In order to get data from another collection you can use `$lookup` (nore efficient) or `populate` (mongoose - considered more organized), so one option is:

```
db.candidate.aggregate([
  {$match: {appliedJobs: {$exists: true}}},
  {$unwind: "$appliedJobs"},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "JobPost",
      localField: "appliedJobs.job",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "appliedJobs"
    }
  },
  {$project: {companyName: {$first: "$appliedJobs.companyName"}}},
  {$group: {_id: {candidate: "$_id", company: "$companyName"}, count: {$sum: 1}}},
  {$group: {
    _id: "$_id.candidate", 
    appliedJobs: {$push: {k: "$_id.company", v: "$count"}}
  }},
  {$project: {appliedJobs: {$arrayToObject: "$appliedJobs"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QQj11n7YOko)

Answer (score 0):

Simply `$unwind` the `appliedJobs` array. Perform `$lookup` to get the `companyName`. Then, `$group` to get count of applications by company.

```js
db.Candidate.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      appliedJobs: {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$appliedJobs"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "JobPost",
      "localField": "appliedJobs._id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "JobPostLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$JobPostLookup"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$JobPostLookup.companyName",
      "Applications": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/meKOAgxY1gp) for your reference.